# Dropbear ssh server immediately quits after startup

Tags: qemu, initramfs, buildroot, dropbear

I built a linux kernel (v. 5.17.1) with default config and created a minimal root fs using buildroot (both for x86_64).
I modified the configuration of buildroot to use glibc and added DHCP for eth0. Furthermore I added a dropbear ssh server.

I can boot into the system using qemu:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1G -kernel linux-5.17.1/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -initrd buildroot-2022.02/output/images/rootfs.cpio -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22
```

The logs state that dropbear (sshd) is started successfully, however the server is not running when trying to connect.
I can start it manually using `/etc/init.d/S50dropbear start`, which also states that it was successful. But it seems to quit right after it started.
If I run dropbear in the *do-not-fork* mode in the foreground, everything is working fine, i. e:

```
dropbear -FBR
```

Does anyone have an idea why this could be the case?

Comment: did you check for logs somewhere else, like `/var/logs`?

Comment: Alright, thanks for the hint (still very much new area for me). Problem was /dev/null was created as a regular file for some reason. Had to fix that using `mknod /dev/null c 1 3`

Comment: Please turn that into an answer of your own question and accept it for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking `/var/log/messages` I noticed dropbear reporting an error: `Early exit: Failed to daemonize: No such device`

The issue was that `/dev/null` was created as a regular file, thus I had to delete it and create it properly:

```
rm /dev/null
mknod /dev/null c 1 3
```